# How to set anlyzer language option warning level?

Tags: dart, lint, analyzer

currently I'm trying to bring type check analyzer to flutter project. however tons of type check error was occuring, so that I changed rule level.  I added warning key to yml, but warning level is not changing. Is there any good way to change analyzer warning level. below code is what I wrote

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    language:
      strict-casts: info
```

Comment: `analyzer: errors: language: ...` seems like the wrong hierarchy.   I think it should be just `analyzer: errors: ERROR_NAME: info`.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#customizing-analysis-rules.  It would help if you provided a specific example of code with analysis failures that you want to ignore.

Comment: Also, if you don't want `strict-casts`, you can disable them: `analyzer: language: strict-casts: false`: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks